# How do i get a methodName in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, methods

var person = { names :{ fname:'felix',lname:'peli'},
age:'52'}

---

Is there a way i can get "fname" as a string from person?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors , but how is the title related to the question?

Comment: `person['names'].fname`

Comment: You mean you want to get the string `"fname"`, not the string `"felix"`? How do you "know" that you want to get the `"fname"` and not the `"lname"`, if you cannot just hardcode the name of the property?

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys` method returns the keys of an object so

```js
var person = {names: { fname: 'felix', lname: 'peli' }, age: '52' }
let fname = Object.keys(person.names) // ["fname", "lname"]
console.log(fname[0]) // "fname"
```